# I am suddenly getting " Unknown error executing apt-key" when attempting to update my system

Tags: apt-key

I have been able to update my system and suddenly I am getting an error

```
Unknown error executing apt-key
```

and I have no idea what caused it.  Also when I attempt any query of the key I get an error

```
/usr/bin/apt-key: 710: touch: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

which I have never gotten on any of the systems on this network and all run the same image.

Comment: can you add some info about which distro/release you are running - similar question here - https://superuser.com/questions/1684891/debian-10-apt-update-suddenly-stopped-working-without-config-change-unknown-err

Comment: Please edit your question and append the results of `sudo ldd /usr/bin/gpg` to it. It should be about 14 lines of output.

Answer (score 3):

1. Reinstall gpg.

   ```
   sudo apt reinstall gpg
   ```
2. Find the location of gpg.

   ```
   which gpg
   > /usr/bin/gpg
   ```
3. Point at the path from the results of `which gpg` and run `ldconfig` on it.

   ```
   sudo ldconfig /usr/bin/gpg
   ```

Comment: Thank you! FIIIIINALLY `sudo apt update` works again for me! I had to use `sudo` or else I got "Permission denied". My final command I ran was `sudo ldconfig /usr/local/bin/gpg` since `which gpg` for me shows `/usr/local/bin/gpg`.

Comment: Turns out I had to use this in my answer here too: [How to install/upgrade to the latest version of Poppler/`pdftoppm` (version 22.11.0 at the time of this writing) on Linux Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74313286/4561887). I've never used `ldconfig` before. Glad I found this answer.